# Чтение из файла txt и запись в словарь пар ключ:значение

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

Имеется файл txt, с информацией вида:

```
[
{
        "country": "Aruba",
        "languages": [
            "Dutch",
            "English",
            "Papiamento",
            "Spanish"
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": "Afghanistan",
        "languages": [
            "Balochi",
            "Dari",
            "Pashto",
            "Turkmenian",
            "Uzbek"
        ]
    }
]
```

необходимо считать из него в новый словарь страны и языки в виде пар, ключ:значение, чтобы получилось:

```
{"Aruba": ["Dutch", "English", "Papiamento", "Spanish"]}
```

испробовал много вариантов, последние мысли резать по строкам и парсить по словам, но с Languages застрял.

```
f = open('countries.txt', 'r')
file = f.read().splitlines()
context = {}
for line in file:
    if "country" in line:
        key,value = line.split(': ')
        context.update({key:value})
print(context)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Формат вашего файла - это в чистом виде [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-ru.html).

Используйте библиотеку для работы с `JSON`, после чего преобразуйте полученный словарь:

```
import json

with open('countries.txt') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    new_data = {x['country']: x['languages'] for x in data}
    print(new_data)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> {'Aruba': ['Dutch', 'English', 'Papiamento', 'Spanish'], 
>  'Afghanistan': ['Balochi', 'Dari', 'Pashto', 'Turkmenian', 'Uzbek']}
> ```

Comment: Спасибо большое!